# Meteor HTTP response content un readable

Tags: meteor

This Meteor server code uses atmosphere HTTP package. I receive human un readable characters from `response.content` even though characters are readable fine in the browser.
Why and how to fix that? Thanks

```
const response = HTTP.call(method, url, {
          timeout: 30000,
          headers: header,
          params: Params,
          followRedirects: true
        }
      );
console.log(response.content);
```

response header has:

```
'content-type': 'text/html'
'content-encoding': 'gzip'
```

request header has:

```
"Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
"Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
```

Comment: Did you try to remove `Accept-Encoding` header?

Comment: Able to read from console.log and NOT able to read from tools like Fiddler?